# Why is Func<T> not called Meth<T>?

Tags: c#, methods, naming

I just used `Action<T>()` and it's sibling `Func<T>()` today and this disturbs my mind now:

`Func<T>` is commented like this in the [official docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.

Since even the comment mentions that is is a method (in C# there is nominally no such thing as functions, AFAIK), **why the designers of C# did not just call that construct 
`Meth<T>` or `Method<T>`?**

Is it probably because of the odd sound of "Meth"? But what about *method*, which would be very clear?

Comment: interesting question, could it be due to VB.Net using Function keyword for methods? you know in vb.Net world, Method is expressed as Function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I regard "method" as a sort of implementation detail here - whereas the mathematical concept of a function is common. (How often have you heard of delegates being described as "function pointers"?)

Note that the word "function" appears even within C# - both anonymous methods and lambda expressions are "anonymous functions".

You use `Func<>` when you want a function - something that returns a value, possibly given some inputs. You don't really care whether or not it's backed by a method; it's just something you can call.

I'd say that the *documentation* for `Func<>` is somewhat lacking here, rather than the choice of name. (Then there's the type system which prevents `Func<void>` being valid, which would make things a lot simpler in numerous situations - but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Func<void> would have removed the need for Action<> would it not? I wonder why they didn't do it like that.

Comment: Wouldn't you then be able to do List<void>?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it would. It would also mean you wouldn't need the non-generic `Task` type - just use `Task<void>` instead.

Comment: @Rob2211: Yes you would - unless you could specify some non-void type argument constraint, perhaps. There would be lots of things to think about, but I think there'd be significant advantages.

Comment: Hm. Is it me or is this starting to sound like a really cool feature that the gods of C# would bestow on us mere mortals one day?

Comment: @Alex: It would have to be a whole CLR feature, I suspect. I doubt that it's worth making the change now, but maybe in the next whole development runtime etc...

Comment: Personally I'm happy with what we have. No really dying for a new hammer now :)

Comment: @RedTaz The problem is that most languages conflate `Void` and `Unit`. `Unit` is the type of 0-tuples, the product of 0 types. There is exactly one such tuple, usually written `()`, and there is nothing you can do with it. It's similar to `null`, except it doesn't violate the type system. `Void` is the union/sum of 0 types. There is no value of type `Void`. A function that "takes no arguments" (which doesn't make sense) should take an argument of type `Unit` and simply ignore it (what else could it do?) There would be no problem with a `List<Unit>`, although it wouldn't be useful in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the other way around. Everything is a function even void MethodName is a function with a void return type.

Comment: That doesn't really work here though, as the `Func` family doesn't support any types with a void return type.

Comment: I think the point is that the two are synonymous. So why has the word function been chosen over method, when the word method is the conventional c# term for what `Func<T>` represents.

Comment: Having read a lot of Eric Lippert's answers :D I imagine this was a design choice to improve code readability perhaps.

Comment: @Alex can you give some links to those answers by Eric?

Comment: @Marcel I meant that in a general sense. He often talks about the design process and how the team reasons about various changes and features to c#. Have a look at http://ericlippert.com/ I'm sure you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I have always considered the terms method and function as being the same thing (as per one of my comments) however, this post; [Difference between a method and a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function) describes the difference where;

> A **method** is a piece of code that is called by name that is associated
>   with an object. In most respects it is identical to a function except
>   for two key differences.
>
> - It is implicitly passed the object for which it was called
> - It is able to operate on data that is contained within the class (remembering that an object is an instance of a class - the class is
>     the definition, the object is an instance of that data)

I think that's the key distinction; `Func<T>` isn't associated with an object it is just a functional "piece of code". The fact that `Func` itself would be an object muddies things slightly, but you get the general idea.

Comment: I agree to your citation in general, but actually, what I do is a call on an object that even accesses a remote database like so: `CreateReport(reportHandler, () => UseCases.Get<MyUseCase>().GetReportData());` where the Func<T> is the call to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was inspired by functional programming. `Func`s are heavily used throughout LINQ as "[purely functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)" methods - that is, methods that return an output for a given input without any observable side effects.

Comment: I think the concept of a function predates the concept of functional programming.